# Mod_Rewrite rewriting directory I dont want it to

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, kohana

So I am using Kohana which is useful if you know it, but not needed to assist me.

I have the following mod_rewrite rules:

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/.*$

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

So I am trying to rewrite all requests for files and directories that do not exist to `index.php`.

However, I want any request sent to `mydomain.com/store/*` to go through as there is another htaccess file in the `store` directory that does work there. That does not seem to be working at the moment. Any ideas?

Full htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

#ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mydomain.com/404Page.html
#Options +FollowSymlinks

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>


RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^myip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/maintenance.html [R=307,L]

##301 Redirect Rules##
#some 301 redirects i did not include here

##Kohana Redirect Rules##

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system|kohana|vendors)\b.* http://www.mydomain.com/ [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?store/

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Note I also tried the following rule `RewriteRule ^store - [L,NC]`

Comment: If `/store` is a physical directory the `!-d` check would be sufficient and `/store` condition won't be necessary. Something is wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @SalmanA You are absolutely correct. I was idiot and did not look to the htaccess file in the actual store direcotry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be in the .htaccess file in the `store` directory not the one in the webroot. Thanks all, and sorry for my stupidity. IF anyone wants to leave comments on how to debug something of this nature for future users that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?store/
```

There is no need to check the characters after the directory. I made the first slash optional if I remeber correctly is the first slash only visible if your server configuration does not contain a tailing slash.

Comment: nah, its still doing it. im gonna post the full file, maybe there is something else i am missing here